# access_token is not defined. How to deserialize json http response and get single items

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to deserialize response from an API(Mpesa) but I'm getting an error access_token not defined and expires_in not defined.
These are json objects returned by the API response

Here is how I'm attempting to create the request and deserialize the response

```
Public Function generateAccessToken() As String
    Dim client = New RestClient("https://api.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials")
    Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.[GET])
    Dim consumer_Key = "Uzy3am875cwhNV7zUxTKIpE4BaPLuWlY"
    Dim consumer_secret = "anard5w4aAzxRqfs"
    Dim credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(consumer_Key & ":" & consumer_secret))
    request.AddHeader("Authorization:", "Basic " & credentials)
    request.AddParameter("text/plain", "", ParameterType.RequestBody)
    Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
    Dim tokenResponse As TokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TokenResponse)(response.Content)
    Return tokenResponse.ToString
End Function
```

Here is my TokenResponse class which contains the two properties for a successful response

```
Public Class TokenResponse
  <JsonProperty(access_token)>
     Public Property AccessCode As String
  <JsonProperty(expires_in)>
    Public Property ExpiryDate As Integer
End Class
```

I expect to get the values from the JSON response but the above error is thrown when I try to run the program. If I comment out the two properties in TokenRespnse class, the following exception is thrown

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MpesaIntegration.exe at this line Dim tokenResponse As TokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TokenResponse)(response.Content)

How can I solve this issue(s) or any idea how to achieve the deserialization of response which looks like this

```json
{
  "access_token": "ivpUQfeM1oegNzMSLe3NVrqvmQiO",
  "expires_in": "3599"
}
```

What I want is simply to return the access_token to the calling function

Comment: You should have, e.g., `<JsonProperty("access_token")>` (with double quotes) -- The second exception is cased by a null / empty response body, so you have to check whether you're sending correct auth credentials or whatever else (I don't know that API and you didn't post a link to the documentation) -- If you're using RestSharp, you can get a deserialized JSON directly (`GetJson()` or `GetJsonAsync()`), it uses System.Text.Json by default, not Json.Net, so the Property attribute changes in `JsonPropertyName(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you casting the "TokenResponse" which is an object "ToString", however you should probably specify the "AccessCode" (which you mapped to "access_token") something like this:

```
Return tokenResponse.AccessCode.ToString()
```

However your error is a System.NullReferenceException so you should probably perform a "tokenResponse is not null" evalauation before attempting the "ToString()" or you will get this error.

Comment: FYI for VB the "is not null" test is spelled `IsNot Nothing`.